# Would it be able to create an iphone app that doesn't use the internet by wifi or 3G but sends out information using the WIFI on the phone

Tags: android, ios, ios4

Would it be possible to make a phone app compatible for IOS and Android, where users who have downloaded the application can send messages / view profiles without an internet connection / 3G.

Essentially, users would have to be within a certain distance of one another and the app would need to use the Wifi in their phones (with no internet)

They could then view local users profiles (in the wifi range of their phone) and view profiles / send messages, enabling communication in areas with no internet / signal etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternatively options like Bluetooth, NFC tags etc. But you need to keep in mind the limited feature of these libraries.